# PyQt4 - Adding multiple grid layouts to a tab widget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm using PyQt4, and Python 2.7.  Initially I had a QGridLayout laid out with two table widgets, and some misc. stuff.

```
self.table_left = QtGui.QTableWidget(self)
self.table_right = QtGui.QTableWidget(self)
self.label_desired = QtGui.QLabel(self)
self.line = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
self.label_current = QtGui.QLabel(self)

self.grid = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
self.grid.addWidget(self.table_left, 0, 0, 20, 1)
self.grid.addWidget(self.table_right, 0, 1, 20, 1)
self.grid.addWidget(self.label_desired, 0, 2, 1, 3)
self.grid.addWidget(self.line, 1, 2, 1, 3)
self.grid.addWidget(self.label_current, 2, 2, 1, 3)
```

But now I want to use a for loop to generate these tables, and GridLayout, and add them to a tabwidget,

```
for k, value in enumerate(self.form_no):
    self.grid[k] = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
    self.grid[k].addWidget(self.table_left[k], 0, 0, 20, 1)
    self.grid[k].addWidget(self.table_right[k], 0, 1, 20, 1)
    self.grid[k].addWidget(self.label_desired[k], 0, 2, 1, 3)
    self.grid[k].addWidget(self.line[k], 1, 2, 1, 3)
    self.grid[k].addWidget(self.label_current[k], 2, 2, 1, 3)
    self.tabwidget.addTab(self.grid[k], str(value))
```

When I tried this I got a type error.  I looked around and couldnt find anything like a GridWidget.  How can I get around this error to add the GridLayouts to a tab widget?

```
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QTabWidget.addTab(QWidget, QString): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QGridLayout'
  QTabWidget.addTab(QWidget, QIcon, QString): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QGridLayout'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `QWidget` to the tab instead of adding a `QLayout`: `self.tabwidget.addTab(widget)`. Then set the `self.grid[k]` to be the layout for this widget: `widget.setLayout(self.grid[k])`.

```
widget = QtGui.QWidget()
widget.setLayout(self.grid[k])
tabwidget.addTab(widget, str(value))
```

Comment: I get an error saying it self.tabWidget doesn't have a .addWidget

  
`self.tabwidget.addWidget(self.table_widget[k],  str(value))
AttributeError: 'QTabWidget' object has no attribute 'addWidget`'

Comment: Sorry it's addTab: fixed answer.